# Hooking my program with windows explorer's rename event

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

Is there any way, in any language, to hook my program when a user renames a file?

For example:
A user renames a file and presses enter (or clicks away) to confirm the rename action. BEFORE the file is actually renamed, my program "listens" to this event and pops up a message saying "Are you sure you want to rename C:\test\file.txt to C:\test\test.txt?".

I'm thinking/hoping this is possible with C++, C# or .NET.. But I don't have any clue where to look for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably solve this by using the [FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) in .NET framework.

From the class remarks:

> You can watch for renaming, deletion,
>   or creation of files or directories.
>   For example, to watch for renaming of
>   text files, set the Filter property to
>   "*.txt" and call the WaitForChanged
>   method with a Renamed specified for
>   its parameter.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is *not* possible, I did find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776794(VS.85).aspx) which is for monitoring operations (including rename) on a folder, but there does not appear to be a similar method for files.

@Richard, FileSystemWatcher is good if you only need to monitor changes, but he needs to interrupt them which it cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

[`IFileOperationProgressSink.PreRenameItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775745(VS.85).aspx) is the closest supported thing I know of. Unfortunately, it's not a hook into Explorer - so you can only use it for your own `IFileOperation` actions. Depending on your needs, you can write a shell extension to do your own `ConfirmRename` (or something), and branch from there.

Otherwise, you're looking at hooking `SHFileOperation`, I think. This would have to be done in unmanaged code, as you'll be loaded into Explorer.exe. For Vista, this has been changed to `IFileOperation` - which probably means you'll have to hook the creation of it and pass out your mock.

Personally, I think since you're talking a rename, [wilhelmtell's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644/hooking-my-program-with-windows-explorers-rename-event#24742) of confirming *after* the change, and undoing it if necessary is the best idea.